# POST array error: Response status code was unacceptable 403

Tags: arrays, swift2, httpresponse, alamofire

I am trying to POST an array with `Alamofire` but I am getting this error

> Request failed with error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 403" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 403}

I want send my array in a request body like this:

```
{
  "ratings":[{
  "safety_rating_id": 105
  "schedule_job_id": 18,
  "score": 9,
  "submission_id": 27
},{
  "safety_rating_id": 106
  "schedule_job_id": 18,
  "score": 10,
  "submission_id": 27
}
```

This is my code

```
func getTaskDetails(onCompletion: () -> (), onError: ((NSError) -> ())? = nil) {

    guard let token = Data.sharedInstance.token else { print("Empty token"); return }


    let Auth_header = [
        "Authorization" : token,
        ]

    let parameters = [
        "ratings"   : [
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 106,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 10,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ],
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 105,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 9,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ]
        ]
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.submitScoreEndpoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
            onCompletion()
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }

    }

}
```